# Unable to print the data fetched by the controller.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs

I am new to this and i am trying to make a dummy contact list.
I have printed the log which fetches the data from mongodb and i can see the correct data in browser console,but when i try to print it in html file it doesn't display.

Here are the snippets:

**controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
$http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response){
console.log("I got the response");
console.log(response); //able to see correct data is fetched in the browser console
$scope.contactlist=response;
});
}])
```

Table where i try to print this data:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="Contact in contactlist">
        <td>{{Contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{Contact.email}}</td>
        <td>{{Contact.number}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Please explain what is going wrong.

Response shown in console:
[image]

Comment: Are there any error in console ?

Comment: is contactlist a List ? Can you paste your response ?

Comment: there are no errors shown in the console

Comment: You need to use callback function to fetch those data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is always synchronous. So what is happening here, `$scope.contactlist=response;` is executing  before `$http.get('/contactlist')...` completed. It means, `$scope.contactlist` undefined. To Solve this problem,
I recommend to use `Service`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService){

  dataService.contactLists(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.contactlist=response.data;
  });

});
}])

myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
    this.contactLists = function(callback){
   $http.get('/contactlist').then(callback)
  }
});
```