# Ionic ng-repeat not working

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code, which doesn't seem to be working correctly, the shop.php loads fine in browser, however on ionic it doesn't seem to show in the loop at all.

What I'm trying to do is loop through an sql query with the merch data inside the ionic view, with ng-repeat but it doesn't seem to work at all, in the source list view of the browser console I can see it being loaded and comes up with the data but doesn't show

Controller:

```js
.controller('shopCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory,$stateParams) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    var sid = $scope.session_id;
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {



        var sload = 'https://app.one3community.com/shop.php';
        $http.post(sload).then(function (res){
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.merch = response.data;
        });
   
    }
})
```

Html:

```html
<ion-view title="rides" id="page16">
<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">SHOP</h1>
</div>
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header" style="margin-top: 44px;">
<div ng-repeat="shop in merch">
          <div class="col-demo">
   <div class="list card">

          <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Nine_Inch_Nails_logo.svg/220px-Nine_Inch_Nails_logo.svg.png">
            <h2>{{shop.image}}</h2>
            <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
          </div>

          <div class="item item-image">
            <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41D5vU4I1NL.jpg">
          </div>

          <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#">
            <i class="ion-android-cart"></i>
            £10.00
          </a>

       </div>
     </div>

</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Php:

```html
<?php
 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

//Allow all domain names to be accessed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');

$content_type_args = explode(';', $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);
if ($content_type_args[0] == 'application/json') {
    $_REQUEST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
};
 
//used to establish connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
 
// query to retrieve the products
$query="SELECT * FROM oneThree_merchandises";
 
//generates the result
$result = $conn->query($query);
$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"image":"'  . $rs["image"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"image_format":"'   . $rs["image_format"]        . '",';

 $outp .= '"id":"'. $rs["id"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"test":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();
 
//outputs the content
echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: it's not ionic problem. See my another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42726272/1960558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems.

1. You are using `$http.post` but it should be `$http.get`
2. `console.log(response.data);
           $scope.merch = response.data;` it should be `console.log(res.data);
           $scope.merch = res.data;`

And JavaScript is always synchronous. So what is happening here, `$scope.merch`; is executing before `$http.get('/..')`... completed. It means, `$scope.merch` undefined. To Solve this problem, I recommend to use Service.

For more see my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42726272/1960558

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can't believe I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think ng-repeat is working, the problem is with **merch** variable It's probably null because it's equal to **response.data**, and response is not defined. It should be **res.data** instead.